# Chunk processing of JDBC ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a database that I am accessing via JDBC.
As I retrieve data, I perform multiple CPU bounded operations on the data.

The DB data is several TB large, so it will surely not completely fit into memory.

The stages look like the follow:

```
(Fetch from JDBC) -> (Perform bulk operation 1) -> (Perform bulk operation 2) -> (Perform bulk operation 3)
```

The arrows depict a high-performance in-memory eventbus that we can abstract from the problem.

The interface between (Fetch from JDBC) and (Perform bulk operation 1) steps expects a  ResultSet - but this is not set in stone.

**My question is**:

In the scenario I want to provide chunks of 1000 rows to "Perform bulk operation 1" - with means writing those rows to the event bus and then continuing fetching the next 1k rows:

How could I provide these 1k rows the downstream consumer **without having to modify the query to the database** (e.g. modifying the SQL statements to perform some pagination via Dialect)?

I see that there's two possibilities solutions that the accepted answer could be based on:

Option (1): keeping the ResultSet contract, but using an implementation where the ResultSet that enables to extract a certain number of rows from the original ResultSet.

Option (2): With another similar data structure not following the ResultSet API, but fast mapping from ResultSet to it whilst keeping similar informations (e.g. schema). The solution in this case would need to be efficient to avoid heap pollution.

Comment: Are these “bulk operations” performed on the database, or in Java? If on the database, you have no need to drag the rows through a `ResultSet`.

Comment: There are in performed in java. It's equivalent to paginating a result set. An example of an operation of an bulk operation 1 would be using a core to convert certain data to Parquet while another task fetching data from the DB is blocked by network I/O

Comment: `ResultSet` already comes in chunks. That's what `Statement.setFetchSize()` is for.

Comment: @user207421 it seems that this depends on the DB implementation of the driver. My understanding is that in DBs like Mysql this is not true. If in the above process I provided ResultSet as it is to the downstream consumer, I would make it network bound.